# Copy a file from PDA to PC via USB in java

Tags: java, file, windows-mobile, java-me, usb

In my application I want to copy a file from PDA to PC via USB, using Java.

But I don't have any idea about how to do this and what API to use for that?

Comment: Can you explain more on where your Java code is running. Is it running on the PC or the PDA, and which kind of PDA you are using. Most PCs will simply see a file system when you plugin the PDA and then you can just use the Java File I/O to transfer files.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [RAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920177.aspx) in order to do this. In order to access the RAPI dll from Java you can either use JNI or a library like this [NativeCall](http://johannburkard.de/software/nativecall/).

Answer (score 0):

I have post describing how to do this in .NET, although it doesn't directly solve your problem it does demonstrate which methods to use in RAPI and how to use them.

http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2007/06/copying-files-from-device-to-desktop.html